# How to add variable number of ModelForms to Template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a page where I can create as much objects as User wants.

For simplicity, there is a simple model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

There is a form:

```
class PersonCreationForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now what I want is to allow user to create as much "persons" as they can. So at first, they can see only one or two `PersonCreationForm`'s, but they can add another forms by themselves.

In fact, in my case, it could be limited (let's say max 20 forms)

Something like the + at the bottom:

[image: Here you can see something similar]

I've already tried this desperate thing:

```
{% for i in "xxxx" %} # tried to create 4 forms...
     {{ person_creation_form | crispy }}
{% endfor %}
```

I've read documentation about `FormSets` but it does not helped.

FormSets:

views.py:

```
from django.forms import formset_factory
PersonCreationFormSet = formset_factory(PersonCreationForm,extra=2,max_num=1)

def PersonCreationView(request):
    formset = PersonCreationFormset()
    return render(request,'person-creation.html',context={'formset':formset}
```

person-creation.html:

```
        {{ formset }} # Tried both ways (commented too)
{#            {% for x in formset %}#}
{#                {{ x | crispy }}#}
{#            {% endfor %}#}
```

No mather what is lower (extra or max_num), the lower number is the number of forms in html and I'm not able to call new forms)

Comment: Formsets are exactly what you want here. What was missing in the documentation?

Comment: It did not work (I've forgot to add extra=somenumber). But still, I'm not able to create as much forms as I want. When I put extra=4, there are 4, is it possible to make it like on the picture?

Comment: In django's admin site, this is handled for you. If you're doing this outside of django's admin, you'll have to handle adding more forms to the formset on your own. There are several ways you can do this, including using javascript & ajax to `render_to_string` another form to the formset. Also note, when doing this, you'll need to modify the formset's hidden fields values.

Comment: Guys, I've added my attempt (bottom of the question), the problem is that there is always fixed number of forms. I've tried already {{formset.media}}